# Using Segoe WP Light in Windows Phone 8.1 apps

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Is it possible to use Segoe WP Light in Windows Phone 8.1 applications? I would like to use the font in a pivot title, but it doesn't work. I can use SemiLight but not Light. Any ideas why?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PivotTitleTemplate">
    <TextBlock
        Margin="-1,0,0,0"
        FontFamily="Segoe WP Light"
        FontSize="20"
        Text="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message, or is the text simply not displaying? Have you tried using "Segoe WP Light" on a normal TextBlock on a normal page, i.e. outside a DataTemplate?

Comment: I found a solution, but this seems to me like a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem.

To use Segoe WP Light, set the font family to Segoe WP and its weight to light. To use Segoe WP SemiLight, set the font family to Sego WP SemiLight and its weight to normal.

For some reason, Visual Studio does not render the fonts properly. Sometimes, it's possible to get the fonts rendered properly if you use the properties windows to set them. However, this only works until you modify any code or switch tabs. Fortunately, on a real device, all fonts are rendered properly.